# How to check the different combination of a particular word in python?

Tags: python, c#, html, python-3.x, list

I am trying to get unique skill set from list and store in a database table, condition is that table should contain unique skill, i.e. it shouldn't contain repeated skill.
like ['HTML', 'Html', 'html', 'H T M L', 'CSS', 'css','Css', 'HTML/css', 'html/css',
'Html/css', 'HTML/Css'] it should be treated as ['html', css].

Answer (score 1):

You can lowercase and remove the spaces in your list (where original_list is the list you provided us) using:

```
lowercased = [x.lower() for x in original_list]
nospaces = [x.replace(" ","") for x in lowercased]
```

For the case where skills are separated by a slash you can split these into their individual constituents and then flatten the resulting list of lists:

```
slash_separated = [x.split("/") for x in nospaces]
flattened_list = [item for sublist in slash_separated for item in sublist]
```

Finally you can deduplicate the list by casting to a set and then list again.

```
deduplicated = list(set(flattened_list))
```

Comment: How to handle different use case for 'Java script', 'Js', 'js', 'java script'?

Comment: The above will work for 'Java Script' and it's variations, turning it into 'javascript'. This approach will not be suitable for acronyms or mis-spellings however, for this you may be better to build a dictionary of mappings of various acronyms and the skills they represent.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
This should solve your purpose.

```
import re

def flat_me_(unflat_lst):
    # METHOD 1 : To Flatten List
    flat_list_tmp = [item for sublist in unflat_lst for item in sublist]
    # END METHOD 1
    
    # METHOD 2 : To Flatten List
    #import itertools
    #flat_list = list(itertools.chain(*list2d))
    # END METHOD 2
    return flat_list_tmp

# input_list_skills = ['HTML', 'Html', 'html', 'H T M L', 'CSS', 'css','Css', 'HTML/css', 'html/css', 'Html/css', 'HTML/Css', 'js', 'JS', 'java script', 'Java Script']
# input_list_skills = [ 'JSP', 'jQuery', 'Java, JavaScript, Angular 2, Hibernate, JPA, JDBC, Apache CXF, Apache POI', 'JSON', 'Oracle Database', 'JAVA/J2EE', 'core and advanced Java', 'Object Oriented Design (OOD) & Analysis (OOA)', 'Java,Webservices,Ajax', 'Interfaces to', 'SOAP', 'B’lore', 'OOPS, Collection Framework, Exception Handling', 'Servlets', 'SpringIOC', 'Core Java7,8, JDBC, EJB, Hibernate, JPA, JMS, Oracle SQL, WebLogic.', 'JNDI FRAME WORKS', 'Jasper Reports', 'Java 8, Angular 6 , Angular 7, Hibernate, JPA, XML Data management MySQL, Oracle Tools Gitlab, GoCD, Coverity, IntelliJ, Eclipse']
input_list_skills = ['hibernate', 'webservices', '', 'j2ee', 'jms', 'angular', 'springboot,java8,angular6,angular7,gocd,hibernate,jpa,nodejs,mediaquery,cssflexbox,jasmineframework', 'corejava', 'jndiframeworks', 'jasperreports', 'corejava7,8,jdbc,ejb,hibernate,jpa,jms,oraclesql,weblogic.', 'java8/j2ee/java7,angular6,angular7,hibernate,jpa,jdbcwebtechnologiesrest,j2ee,html5,css3datamodellingjson,xmldatamanagementmysql,oracletoolsgitlab,gocd.,coverity,intellij,eclipse', 'java,', 'html', 'spring,springboot,springmvc,iocwebserver', 'tomcat', 'c++', 'git', 'java', 'intellij', 'uml', 'junit', 'webservices' ]

# These are manual keywords, user wants to remove from the input text. Exhaustive list will improve solution
keywords_to_replace = ['core', 'advanced', 'advance', 'and']

# Splitting Text on comma(,) and forward-slash(/)
list2d = [re.split(',|/', x.lower()) for x in input_list_skills]

# Flattening List
flat_list = flat_me_(list2d)

# Removing Integers and dots(.) from the string, along with white spaces
list2d = [re.split(',|/', re.sub("^\s+|\s+$", "", re.sub('\d|\.', '', x), flags=re.UNICODE)) for x in flat_list]

# Flattening List
flat_list = flat_me_(list2d)

# Removing words which are not required, along with white spaces
flat_list = [re.sub("^\s+|\s+$", "", re.sub(r"" + '|'.join(keywords_to_replace) + "", '', x)) for x in flat_list]

final_unq_skills = list(set(flat_list))
final_unq_skills.remove('')

# Final Output
print(final_unq_skills)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['jasmineframework', 'git', 'jasperreports', 'nodejs', 'oraclesql', 'jee', 'springboot', 'cssdatamodellingjson', 'ejb', 'xmldatamanagementmysql', 'angular', 'jdbc', 'jndiframeworks', 'springmvc', 'uml', 'jpa', 'html', 'spring', 'jms', 'java', 'oracletoolsgitlab', 'coverity', 'c++', 'mediaquery', 'junit', 'tomcat', 'iocwebserver', 'intellij', 'hibernate', 'gocd', 'weblogic', 'cssflexbox', 'eclipse', 'webservices', 'jdbcwebtechnologiesrest']
```

Comment: Can you share your sample list? and expected output?

Comment: [ 'JSP', 'jQuery', 'Java, JavaScript, Angular 2, Hibernate, JPA, JDBC, Apache CXF, Apache POI',  'JSON', 'Oracle Database', 'JAVA/J2EE',  'core and advanced Java', 'Object Oriented Design (OOD) & Analysis (OOA)', 'Java,Webservices,Ajax', 'Interfaces to', 'SOAP', 'B’lore', 'OOPS, Collection Framework, Exception Handling', 'Servlets', 'SpringIOC',  'Core Java7,8, JDBC, EJB, Hibernate, JPA, JMS, Oracle SQL, WebLogic.', 'JNDI FRAME WORKS', 'Jasper Reports', 'Java 8, Angular 6 , Angular 7, Hibernate, JPA,  XML Data management MySQL, Oracle Tools Gitlab, GoCD, Coverity, IntelliJ, Eclipse']

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: ['html', JavaScript', 'css',  'jquery', 'java'........] list without duplicate values

Comment: Java 8 and Java 7 will be java in this list and not 2 separate entities. right?
Version number is not required for your use case?

Comment: Share your input string will check the cause and will handle the exception
Or try to remove .lower() from this line and rerun.. see if this error goes away..
# Removing Integers and dots(.) from the string, along with white spaces 
list2d = [re.split(',|/', re.sub("^\s+|\s+$", "", re.sub('\d|\.', '', x), flags=re.UNICODE)) for x in list2d]

Comment: ['hibernate', 'webservices', 'javascript', 'j2ee', 'jms', 'angular', 'springboot,java8,angular6,angular7,gocd,hibernate,jpa,nodejs,mediaquery,cssflexbox,jasmineframework', 'corejava', 'jndiframeworks',  'jasperreports', corejava7,8,jdbc,ejb,hibernate,jpa,jms,oraclesql,weblogic.', 'java8/j2ee/java7,angular6,angular7,hibernate,jpa,jdbcwebtechnologiesrest,j2ee,html5,css3datamodellingjson,xmldatamanagementmysql,oracletoolsgitlab,gocd.,coverity,intellij,eclipse', 'java,', 'html', 'spring,springboot,springmvc,iocwebserver', 'tomcat', 'c++', 'git', 'java', 'intellij', 'uml', 'junit', 'webservices' ]

Comment: I have update the code. Please try to run this on your input and production